# Por que não consigo executar o arquivo localizado no bin?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, terminal

Preciso usar o arquivo `flare` e `flasm`, os quais o chown e a permissão estão corretas. Por que consigo executar somente um e o outro não?

```
    -rwxr-xr-x  1 daniela.morais sudo    64808 Mar 19 13:54 flare*
    -rwxr-xr-x  1 daniela.morais sudo   108525 Mar 19 13:48 flasm*
    daniela.morais@tusk:/usr/local/bin$ flare

    Flare 0.6 build Jun 11 2007

    Copyright (c) 2003-2005 Igor Kogan
    All rights reserved. See LICENSE.TXT for terms of use.

    Usage: flare filename.swf
    Decompiled ActionScript code is stored in filename.flr.
    daniela.morais@tusk:/usr/local/bin$ flasm
    bash: /usr/local/bin/flasm: No such file or directory
```

Flare: http://www.nowrap.de/flare.html
Flasm: http://www.nowrap.de/flasm.html

Comment: Esse `flasm` é um arquivo mesmo, ou um link simbólico? (se for um link, talvez o arquivo não exista no local onde esse link está apontando...) Se estiver na dúvida, [experimente `ls -la`](http://askubuntu.com/q/522051/68847)

Comment: @mgibsonbr É um arquivo mesmo. O asterisco no final do nome do arquivo indica que se trata de um executável.

Comment: As permissões estão corretas, qual a saída do comando `which flasm`? não sei se é o caso, mas tente também atualizar o cache desse arquivo com `hash -d flasm`, o *path* para o seu comando pode ter sido armazenado em cache com um valor errado.

Comment: adicionalmente ao que já foi sugerido, pode atualizar o post com a saída do comando `file flare flasm`? Apenas pra termos certeza de que ambos os arquivos podem ser executados.

Comment: @Qmechanic73, o asterisco na saída do comando `ls` apenas indica que o arquivo possui permissão de execução devido a alguma configuração de inicialização do shell. Isso não tem relação nenhuma com ele ser executável ou não.

Comment: @BrunoCoimbra Posso ter interpretado errado o que está escrito [aqui](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-output-formatting.html). =)

Comment: @Qmechanic73 daniela.morais@tusk:~$ which flasm
/usr/local/bin/flasm
daniela.morais@tusk:~$ hash -d flasm
daniela.morais@tusk:~$ flasm
bash: /usr/local/bin/flasm: No such file or directory

Comment: @BrunoCoimbra daniela.morais@tusk:/usr/local/bin$ file flare flasm
flare: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.4, stripped
flasm: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, stripped

Comment: daniela.morais@tusk:~/Downloads/config$ file flasm
flasm: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, stripped

O bizarro que esse mesmo arquivo está instalado numa de 64 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui o/
Faltava instalar esses pacotes:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32z1
```